# Back button behaviour with BottomNavigationView implemented using navigation component

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview, android-navigation

I have created a nav_graph.xml for android navigation component and added four fragments for four different views. Now added [BottomNavigationView](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/bottomnavigation/BottomNavigationView) and menu items , used the fragment ids from nav_graph and provided those ids to each menu items for bottom navigation. It works and shows the particular fragment for selected menu item from bottom nav view.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item android:id="@+id/nav_fragmentA"
          android:title="@string/menu_search"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_search" />
     <item android:id="@+id/nav_fragmentB"
          android:title="@string/menu_settings"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_add" />
     <item android:id="@+id/nav_fragmentC"
          android:title="@string/menu_navigation"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_navigation_menu" />
     <item android:id="@+id/nav_fragmentD"
          android:title="@string/menu_navigation"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_navigation_menu" />
 </menu>
```

Issue:
When user presses any menu items multiple times and presses back button. It navigates through whole back stack rather going to first menu item and exiting the app.

For example

- Four bottom menu items: A B C D
- User navigation: A->C->B->D->B->C-A->D
- Back button behaviour: D->A->C->B->D-B->C->A->Exit (Reverse of user navigation)

Want to achieve the behaviour as below:

- User navigate through menu items: A->C->B->D->B->C-A->D (Any random navigation)
- Back button: D->A->Exit (From any selected item to first item and then exit)

Comment: Can you post code where action is defined?

Comment: @VVB there are no explicit actions defined it works if the same fragment id from the nav_graph.xml provided to the bottom navigation menu items.

Comment: If it is the case then can you show code where replace Fragments is handled?

Comment: @VVB There is not explicit code where I am handling fragment switching. It is handled by navigation component. Refer here for reference implementation https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/blob/master/NavigationAdvancedSample/app/src/main/res/menu/bottom_nav.xml also https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/tree/master/NavigationAdvancedSample/app/src/main/res/navigation

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue.

The integration between the bottom navigation and the navigation component needs a separate nav graph for each fragment/tab and also a parent nav graph that includes all of these tabs.

The parent nav graph **cannot** have any other fragments included within it. It can only have the include tags for each of the tabs.

Example:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:startDestination="@id/home"
    android:id="@+id/bottom_nav">

    <include app:graph="@navigation/frag1" />
    <include app:graph="@navigation/frag2" />
    <include app:graph="@navigation/frag3" />

</navigation>
```

The [sample](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/tree/master/NavigationAdvancedSample/app/src/main/res/navigation) given by architecture components is also helpful.